# SwiftUI: is there exist modifier to highlight substring of Text() view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have some text on the screen:

```
Text("someText1")
```

is it possible to highlight/select part of the text without creating lot Text items

I mean

```
Text("som") + Text("eTex").foregroundColor(.red) + Text("t1")
```

is not solution for me

Better to have some sort of modifier to highlight by some way part of the text. Something similar to:

```
Text("someText1").modifier(.highlight(text:"eTex"))
```

Is it possible? (without creation of lot of views I mean)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Once you create a Text, you cannot open it back up. Your example creates localization problems. `someText1` is not actually the string to print. It's the localization key of the string. The default localized string just happens to be the key, so it works. Your attempt to search for `eTex` would quietly break when you localize. So this wouldn't be a good general-purpose interface.

Even so, building a solution is very enlightening, and may be useful for specific cases.

The fundamental goal is to think of styles as attributes that are applied to ranges. That's exactly what NSAttributedString gives us, including the ability to merge and split ranges in order to manage multiple, overlapping attributes. NSAttributedString is not particularly Swift-friendly, so there could be some value in reimplementing it from scratch, but instead, I'm just going to hide it as an implementation detail.

So a TextStyle is going to be an NSAttributedString.Key and a function that translates a Text into another Text.

```
public struct TextStyle {
    // This type is opaque because it exposes NSAttributedString details and
    // requires unique keys. It can be extended by public static methods.

    // Properties are internal to be accessed by StyledText
    internal let key: NSAttributedString.Key
    internal let apply: (Text) -> Text

    private init(key: NSAttributedString.Key, apply: @escaping (Text) -> Text) {
        self.key = key
        self.apply = apply
    }
}
```

TextStyle is opaque. To construct it, we expose some extensions, for example:

```
// Public methods for building styles
public extension TextStyle {
    static func foregroundColor(_ color: Color) -> TextStyle {
        TextStyle(key: .init("TextStyleForegroundColor"), apply: { $0.foregroundColor(color) })
    }

    static func bold() -> TextStyle {
        TextStyle(key: .init("TextStyleBold"), apply: { $0.bold() })
    }
}
```

It's noteworthy here that NSAttributedString is just "an string annotated by attributes over ranges." It's not "a styled string." We can make up any attribute keys and values we want. So these are intentionally not the same attributes that Cocoa uses for formatting.

Next, we create the StyledText itself. I'm focusing first on the "model" part of this type (later we'll make it a View).

```
public struct StyledText {
    // This is a value type. Don't be tempted to use NSMutableAttributedString here unless
    // you also implement copy-on-write.
    private var attributedString: NSAttributedString

    private init(attributedString: NSAttributedString) {
        self.attributedString = attributedString
    }

    public func style<S>(_ style: TextStyle,
                         ranges: (String) -> S) -> StyledText
        where S: Sequence, S.Element == Range<String.Index>?
    {

        // Remember this is a value type. If you want to avoid this copy,
        // then you need to implement copy-on-write.
        let newAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)

        for range in ranges(attributedString.string).compactMap({ $0 }) {
            let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: attributedString.string)
            newAttributedString.addAttribute(style.key, value: style, range: nsRange)
        }

        return StyledText(attributedString: newAttributedString)
    }
}
```

It's just a wrapper around an NSAttributedString and a way to create new StyledTexts by applying TextStyles to ranges. Some important points:

- Calling `style` does not mutate the existing object. If it did, you couldn't do things like `return StyledText("text").apply(.bold())`. You'd get an error that the value is immutable.
- Ranges are tricky things. NSAttributedString uses NSRange, and has a different concept of index than String. NSAttributedStrings can be a different length than the underlying String because they compose characters differently.
- You can't safely take a `String.Index` from one String and apply it to another String, even if the two Strings seem identical. That's why this system takes a closure for creating ranges rather than taking a range itself. `attributedString.string` is not exactly the same string as the one that was passed in. If the caller wanted to pass `Range<String.Index>`, it would be critical that they construct it with precisely the same string that TextStyle uses. This is easiest to ensure by using a closure and avoids a lot of corner cases.

The default `style` interface handles a sequence of ranges for flexibility. But in most cases you'll probably pass just one range, so it's nice to have a convenience method for that, and for the case where you want the whole string:

```
public extension StyledText {
    // A convenience extension to apply to a single range.
    func style(_ style: TextStyle,
               range: (String) -> Range<String.Index> = { $0.startIndex..<$0.endIndex }) -> StyledText {
        self.style(style, ranges: { [range($0)] })
    }
}
```

Now, the public interface for creating a StyledText:

```
extension StyledText {
    public init(verbatim content: String, styles: [TextStyle] = []) {
        let attributes = styles.reduce(into: [:]) { result, style in
            result[style.key] = style
        }
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: content, attributes: attributes)
    }
}
```

Note the `verbatim` here. This StyledText doesn't support localization. It's conceivable that with work it could, but a lot more thought would have to go into that.

And finally, after all that, we can make it a View, by creating a Text for each substring that has the same attributes, applying all the styles to that Text, and then combining all the Texts into one using `+`. For convenience, the Text is directly exposed so you can combine it with standard views.

```
extension StyledText: View {
    public var body: some View { text() }

    public func text() -> Text {
        var text: Text = Text(verbatim: "")
        attributedString
            .enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length),
                                 options: [])
            { (attributes, range, _) in
                let string = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                let modifiers = attributes.values.map { $0 as! TextStyle }
                text = text + modifiers.reduce(Text(verbatim: string)) { segment, style in
                    style.apply(segment)
                }
        }
        return text
    }
}
```

And that's it. Using it looks like this:

```
// An internal convenience extension that could be defined outside this pacakge.
// This wouldn't be a general-purpose way to highlight, but shows how a caller could create
// their own extensions
extension TextStyle {
    static func highlight() -> TextStyle { .foregroundColor(.red) }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        StyledText(verbatim: "‍‍someText1")
            .style(.highlight(), ranges: { [$0.range(of: "eTex"), $0.range(of: "1")] })
            .style(.bold())
    }
}
```

[image: Image of text with red highlighting and bold]

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/a37cdbf4aabb1e4a6b40436efc2c3114)

You could also just wrap a UILabel in a UIViewRepresentable, and use `attributedText`. But that would be cheating. :D

Comment: This is truly amazing. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Rob, I'm curious to hear your ideas on how could we add support for a style similar to NSBackgroundColorAttributeName. The challenge with applying a .background() modifier to a Text, is that the return type becomes a View. Your implementation relies on the fact that applying a style to a Text will return a Text, which would not be the case when applying .background modifier. I don't think we can package a View back into a Text, but I'm curious to hear your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: How many times can I upvote this? Just 1? :(

Comment: “ You could also just wrap a UILabel in a UIViewRepresentable, and use attributedText. But that would be cheating. :D” - may I ask why that would be cheating?

Answer (score 11):

**Disclaimer**: I was really reluctant to post my answer since I am sure that there must be a lot of way-smarter, way-better (I dunno maybe a wrapper to a UIKit view using TextKit) and more robust approaches, but... what the heck I thought it was a fun exercise and maybe someone could actually benefit from it.

So here we go:

Instead of a modifier, I'm going to make a view that holds a string (to render) and another one to hold our 'matching' text.

```
struct HighlightedText: View {
    let text: String
    let matching: String

    init(_ text: String, matching: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.matching = matching
    }

    var body: some View {
        let tagged = text.replacingOccurrences(of: self.matching, with: "<SPLIT>>\(self.matching)<SPLIT>")
        let split = tagged.components(separatedBy: "<SPLIT>")
        return split.reduce(Text("")) { (a, b) -> Text in
            guard !b.hasPrefix(">") else {
                return a + Text(b.dropFirst()).foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            return a + Text(b)
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the code is quite self-explanatory but in a nutshell:

1. Find all matches
2. Replace them by hardcoded 'tags' (marking the beginning of a match by another hardcoded character)
3. Split on the tags
4. Reduce the components & return a stylized version if we're on a match

Now, we can use it with something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var matching: String = "ll"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Matching term", text: self.$matching)
            HighlightedText("Hello to all in this hall", matching: self.matching)
            .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Here is a (crappy) gif demonstrating it in action:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/II3bh.jpg

[image]

Finally, in case you're wondering how I'm running SwiftUI outside Xcode, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/alladinian/0f6bd22fb7591a9b1782c1fa3ef4f24c) I've made for prototyping quickly in SwiftUI on the Mac

Comment: How can you add a background color (highlighter effect) instead of only colouring the text? If I add a background, it is no longer considered to be a view 

Comment: @simibac Nice observation... From what I can see this might be actually not possible in pure SwiftUI (yet). I guess someone would have to rely on UIKit and wrap it into a representable.

Comment: Looks like a cool solution! I'm trying to do this same highlighting but for the text in a TextField() view. Any way you think this could be possible?

Comment: @Lars Since this method is relying on styled `Text` concatenation and `TextField` doesn't provide a way to be initialized by `Text`, I cannot see how it could be done (but I would be glad to be wrong, cause I'd also like to know if it's actually possible by any other means)

Comment: So typical of a great programmer. Never believe you have the best solution but you do!

Comment: @xtabbas wow, thanks a lot for your kind words man :) You got some really high-quality blog posts btw!

Comment: have you ever tried to enter "he" instead of "He"? Unfortunately, this is not case insensitive

Comment: @PeterKreinz You are right, it is not. The string matching part is the simplest possible in this example, but I guess someone could easily modify it and use a regex search/replace instead.

Comment: This is great! for case insensitivity i've added  - options: .caseInsensitive to the text.replacingOccurrences func

Answer (score 5):

I like the simple solution of @Alladinian very much, but I need a solution that is  case insensitive e.g. for a typeahead highlighting of the characters entered.

Here is my modification using regex:

```
struct HighlightedText: View {
    let text: String
    let matching: String
    let caseInsensitiv: Bool

    init(_ text: String, matching: String, caseInsensitiv: Bool = false) {
        self.text = text
        self.matching = matching
        self.caseInsensitiv = caseInsensitiv
    }

    var body: some View {
        guard  let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: matching).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).folding(options: .regularExpression, locale: .current), options: caseInsensitiv ? .caseInsensitive : .init()) else {
            return Text(text)
        }

        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range)

        return text.enumerated().map { (char) -> Text in
            guard matches.filter( {
                $0.range.contains(char.offset)
            }).count == 0 else {
                return Text( String(char.element) ).foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            return Text( String(char.element) )

        }.reduce(Text("")) { (a, b) -> Text in
            return a + b
        }
    }
}
```

> Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var matching: String = "he"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Matching term", text: self.$matching)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
            HighlightedText("Hello to all in this hall", matching: self.matching, caseInsensitiv: true)
            .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the solutions from Alladinian and Peter Kreinz, I needed an implementation that also ignored "diacritic accents" during the search and subsequent match. It uses the parameters caseInsensitive and diacriticInsensitive, and they seem to work well. For anyone who might find it useful...

Code:

```
struct HighlightedText: View {

let text: String
let matching: String
let highlightColor: Color
let caseInsensitive: Bool
let diacriticInsensitive: Bool

/** INIT */
init(
    _ text: String,
    matching: String,
    highlightColor: Color = .blue,
    caseInsensitive: Bool = true,
    diacriticInsensitive: Bool = true
) {
    self.text = text
    self.matching = matching
    self.highlightColor = highlightColor
    self.caseInsensitive = caseInsensitive
    self.diacriticInsensitive = diacriticInsensitive
}

/** BODY */
var body: some View {
    
    // Create string comparison options based on the chosen settings
    var compareOptions: String.CompareOptions = []
    if caseInsensitive {
        compareOptions.insert(.caseInsensitive)
    }
    if diacriticInsensitive {
        compareOptions.insert(.diacriticInsensitive)
    }

    // Find the range of the matching text
    let matchingRange = text.range(of: matching, options: compareOptions, range: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, locale: .current)

    // Create a Text with highlighted matches
    return text.indices.map { index -> Text in
        
        if let range = matchingRange, range.contains(index) {
            return Text(String(text[index]))
                .foregroundColor(highlightColor)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            
        } else {
            return Text(String(text[index]))
        }
        
    }.reduce(Text("")) { (a, b) -> Text in
        return a + b
    }
}
```

}

And here's an example to view in Preview:

```
struct HighlightedText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        
        HighlightedText(
        """
        «Este mi amo, por mil señales, he visto que es un loco de atar, y aun también yo no le quedo en zaga, pues soy más mentecato que él, pues le sigo y le sirvo, si es verdadero el refrafán que dice: ‘Dime con quién andas, decirte he quién eres’, y el otro de ‘No con quien naces, sino con quien paces'».
        """,
        matching: "mentecato"
        )
        .padding()
        
        HighlightedText(
        """
        «Advierte, Sancho–dijo don Quijote–, que el amor ni mira respectos ni guarda términos de razón en sus discursos, y tiene la misma condición que la muerte: que así acomete los altos alcázares de los reyes como las humildes chozas de los pastores, y cuando toma entera posesión de una alma, lo primero que hace es quitarle el temor y la vergüenza».
        """,
        matching: "terminos",// without diacritic accent
        highlightColor: Color.red
        )
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less idiomatic variant of Rob's solution above it to use existing NSAttributedString keys (useful if you already have code that generates NSAttributedStrings). This just handles font and foregroundColor, but you could add others.

Question: I'd like to add links to some of the text elements, but I can't do this because once Text is modified with a tap gesture (or replaced with a link), it's no longer composable with other Text values. Is there an idiomatic way around this?

```swift
extension NSAttributedString.Key {
    func apply(_ value: Any, to text: Text) -> Text {
        switch self {
        case .font:
            return text.font(Font(value as! UIFont))
        case .foregroundColor:
            return text.foregroundColor(Color(value as! UIColor))
        default:
            return text
        }
    }
}

public struct TextAttribute {
    let key: NSAttributedString.Key
    let value: Any
}

public struct AttributedText {
    // This is a value type. Don't be tempted to use NSMutableAttributedString here unless
    // you also implement copy-on-write.
    private var attributedString: NSAttributedString
    
    public init(attributedString: NSAttributedString) {
        self.attributedString = attributedString
    }
    
    public func style<S>(_ style: TextAttribute,
                         ranges: (String) -> S) -> AttributedText
    where S: Sequence, S.Element == Range<String.Index>
    {
        
        // Remember this is a value type. If you want to avoid this copy,
        // then you need to implement copy-on-write.
        let newAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
        
        for range in ranges(attributedString.string) {
            let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: attributedString.string)
            newAttributedString.addAttribute(style.key, value: style, range: nsRange)
        }
        
        return AttributedText(attributedString: newAttributedString)
    }
}

public extension AttributedText {
    // A convenience extension to apply to a single range.
    func style(_ style: TextAttribute,
               range: (String) -> Range<String.Index> = { $0.startIndex..<$0.endIndex }) -> AttributedText {
        self.style(style, ranges: { [range($0)] })
    }
}

extension AttributedText {
    public init(verbatim content: String, styles: [TextAttribute] = []) {
        let attributes = styles.reduce(into: [:]) { result, style in
            result[style.key] = style
        }
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: content, attributes: attributes)
    }
}

extension AttributedText: View {
    public var body: some View { text() }
    
    public func text() -> Text {
        var text: Text = Text(verbatim: "")
        attributedString
            .enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length),
                                 options: [])
            { (attributes, range, _) in
                let string = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                text = text + attributes.reduce(Text(verbatim: string)) { segment, attribute in
                    return attribute.0.apply(attribute.1, to: segment)
                }
            }
        return text
    }
}

public extension Font {
    init(_ font: UIFont) {
        switch font {
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle):
            self = .largeTitle
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1):
            self = .title
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title2):
            self = .title2
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title3):
            self = .title3
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline):
            self = .headline
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline):
            self = .subheadline
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .callout):
            self = .callout
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1):
            self = .caption
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption2):
            self = .caption2
        case UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote):
            self = .footnote
        default:
            self = .body
        }
    }
}
```