# SwiftUI Put a color to only one word in a sentence with localization

Tags: swift, string, localization, swiftui

I want to put a color to one word of a string placed in a Text().
This word can be placed in different position in the string depending on the localization.

---

### Examples:

(*MYAPP* is the word I want to put in red color)

**In english:**
Hello, welcome in *MYAPP* app.

**In french:**
Bonjour, bienvenue dans l'application *MYAPP*.

---

In my code, I could have used:

```
Text("Hello, welcome in ") 
+ Text("MYAPP").foregroundColor(.red)
+ Text("app")
```

But this is not working because if I use the app in french, the word 'app' will not be placed at the end of the sentence but before *MYAPP*
So I can't use it with localization and I need to.

I've tried stuff like this that i found on the net:

```
let color = UIColor.red;
let textToFind = "redword"
        
let attrsString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string:yourlabel.text!);
        
// search for word occurrence
let range = (yourlabel.text! as NSString).range(of: textToFind)
if (range.length > 0) {
     attrsString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,value:color,range:range)
}
        
// set attributed text
yourlabel.attributedText = attrsString
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62976651/12299030?

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exceeding max Text("") concatenation length - SwiftUI -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975088/exceeding-max-text-concatenation-length-swiftui)

Answer (score 14):

You can use the new string interpolation feature:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("MyLocalizedKey \(Text("Red word").foregroundColor(Color.red))")
    }
}
```

}

And in your Localizable.strings you would have:

```
"MyLocalizedKey %@" = "My name is %@.";
```

Comment: Does that support ordering of two arguments as well?

Comment: Yes it does ;) In one language, you can have "MyLocalizedKey %@" = "My name is %@."; while in other "MyLocalizedKey %@" = "%@ is my name"