# SwiftUI - How to wrap multiple Text views into a paragraph

Tags: swiftui

I want to keep each sentence in the paragraph it's own `Text` view, because it has unique functionality on hover. Currently I'm using the `WrappingHStack` from [here](https://github.com/dkk/WrappingHStack).

```
WrappingHStack(1...6, id:\.self) {
    Text("This is number \($0). ")
}
```

This creates text like this:

```
This is number 1. This is number 2.      | // bounds
This is number 3. This is number 4.      |
This is number 5. This is number 5.      |
```

What I want is like this:

```
This is number 1. This is number 2. This 
is number 3. This is number 4. This is 
number 5. This is number 6.
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

EDIT:

More context on what I'm trying to achieve. Let's say I have two sentences: `Does the seal work?` and `el sello funciona?` When a user hovers on `seal`, I'd like to highlight `sello`(that logic I can implement as the two sentences are structured and broken down). Where i'm struggling is to get text to look like a regular block of text, but to have unique hover behaviour on the sentence/word level.

Comment: Use instead something to generate Text()+Text()+..., like for example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62976651/12299030. Or prepare one concatenated string and use in single Text.

Comment: @Asperi But correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't this then require that the text functions only as a single `Text` view? I tried `Text("One").onHover {...} + Text("Two").onHover { ... }` and this doesn't work. `Text("One") + Text("Two")` achieves the visuals for what I want, but not the other functionality.

Comment: Then your question should be more precise about your scenario and intentions. Yes, Text+Text works only for texts, not for arbitrary views.

Comment: Essentially I want the equivalent of wrapping each sentence in a `<span>` which can have it's own unique hover action. But I'm not sure how to go about this in SwiftUI.

Comment: @Asperi I'm not sure what's not precise about my intentions: `I want to keep each sentence in the paragraph it's own Text view, because it has unique functionality on hover.`

Comment: @Asperi I've added more context on what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can try it

```
ZStack {
            (Text("title-1".localized)
                + Text("title-2".localized)
                + Text("title-3".localized))
                .modifier(TitleTextRegular(foregroundColor: .bronze, font: .title))
        }.frame(width: 800)
```

Answer (score 0):

**@peter** you can achive Text as a paragraph by following code:

```
var varPara: String = ""
for index in 1...6 {
    varPara = varPara != "" ? varPara + " This is number \(index)." : " This is number \(index)."
}
```

**Output:**
"This is number 1. This is number 2. This is number 3. This is number 4. This is number 5. This is number 6."

After that you need to assign string parameter to Text and then give highlight logic to Text.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this just creates a longer string, which I can already do. What I'm trying to have is multiple Text components, that look like a paragraph, but function is a separate words/sentences/etc.