# Text lines background color

Tags: swiftui, uikit, core-graphics

I'm trying to recreate the HTML span *background coloring effect* in SwiftUI. Not the whole bounding view should be colored, only the text lines. Can this be done easily in SwiftUI / UIKit / Core Graphics ?

```css
div {
  max-width: 400px;
  line-height: 2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius, nulla eget consequat finibus, tortor erat scelerisque ipsum, nec dictum justo quam in ipsum. Nulla nec eleifend felis. Sed vel semper mauris, a placerat elit.</span>
</div>
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius, nulla eget consequat finibus, tortor erat scelerisque ipsum, nec dictum justo quam in ipsum. Nulla nec eleifend felis. Sed vel semper mauris, a placerat elit.")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .frame(maxWidth: 200)
            .lineSpacing(6)
    }
}
```

SwiftUI Preview:
[image: SwiftUI Preview]

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74057274/6433023

Answer (score 0):

Closest solution this moment seems to be to ‘hack it’ using AttributedString, which is not the most elegant… And adding padding between background and text seems impossible.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius, nulla eget consequat finibus, tortor erat scelerisque ipsum, nec dictum justo quam in ipsum. Nulla nec eleifend felis. Sed vel semper mauris, a placerat elit."
    var attributedString: AttributedString {
        var attributedString = AttributedString(text)            
        attributedString.foregroundColor = .white
        attributedString.backgroundColor = .blue
        return attributedString
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(attributedString)
            .frame(maxWidth: 300)
            .lineSpacing(6)
    }
}
```

Really wish it were possible to use the text baselines as a CGPath and add multiple rectangles.