# SwiftUI highlight word in search result

Tags: swiftui, uisearchbar

I have a search view, where user can search by a word or phrase and filter the result.

```
        List {
            ForEach(textsData) {text in
                if text.sometext.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchText) || self.searchText == "" {
                    NavigationLink(destination: TextView(text: text)) {
                        Text(text.sometext)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
```

I would like to highlight with red color the searched text. Is there a way I can do it?

**UPD**:
Let's assume the code is as following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var texts = ["This is an example of large text block", "This block is rather small"]
    
    var textsSearch = "large"
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.texts, id: \.self) {text in
                Text(text).padding().background(self.textsSearch == text ? Color.red : .clear)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to highlight only the word "large" in output:

This is an example of **large** text block

This block is rather small

**UPD2**: This answer worked good for me: [SwiftUI: is there exist modifier to highlight substring of Text() view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426359/swiftui-is-there-exist-modifier-to-highlight-substring-of-text-view/59427912#59427912)

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You can often add conditions directly into modifiers:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var texts = ["a", "b"]
    
    var textsSearch = "a"
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.texts, id: \.self) {text in
                Text(text).padding().background(self.textsSearch == text ? Color.red : .clear)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for comment! Unfortunately this works only if text value fully equal to search value.In my case text value may have "This is an example of the large text block" And searchTest may be "large". So I wanted to highlight the word "large" in the text output

Comment: what should i do to highlight the word "large" in such case?

`struct ContentView: View {
    
    var texts = ["This is an example of large text block", "This block is rather small"]
    
    var textsSearch = "large"
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.texts, id: \.self) {text in
                Text(text).padding().background(self.textsSearch == text ? Color.red : .clear)
            }
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, the `text.foregroundColor` it wasn't enough for me. I need to change the `background` color of the view. There isn't a easy way to accomplish this in SwiftUI so I created my own `View` that adds this capability:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HighlightedText: View {

    /// The text rendered by current View
    let text: String
    /// The textPart to "highlight" if [text] contains it
    var textPart: String?

    /// The <Text> views created inside the current view inherits Text params defined for self (HighlightedText) like font, underline, etc
    /// Color used for view background when text value contans textPart value
    var textPartBgColor: Color = Color.blue
    /// Font size used to determine if the current text needs more than one line for render
    var fontSize: CGFloat = 18
    /// Max characters length allowed for one line, if exceeds a new line will be added
    var maxLineLength = 25
    /// False to disable multiline drawing
    var multilineEnabled = true

    /// True when the current [text] needs more than one line to render
    @State private var isTruncated: Bool = false

    public var body: some View {
        guard let textP = textPart, !textP.isEmpty else {
            // 1. Default case, [textPart] is null or empty
            return AnyView(Text(text))
        }

        let matches = collectRegexMatches(textP)
        if matches.isEmpty {
            // 2. [textPart] has a value but is not found in the [text] value
            return AnyView(Text(text))
        }

        // 3. There is at least one match for [textPart] in [text]
        let textParts = collectTextParts(matches, textP)
        if multilineEnabled && isTruncated {
            // 4. The current [text] needs more than one line to render
            return AnyView(renderTruncatedContent(collectLineTextParts(textParts)))
        }

        // 5. The current [text] can be rendered in one line
        return AnyView(renderOneLineContent(textParts))
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func renderOneLineContent(_ textParts: [TextPartOption]) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(textParts) { item in
                if item.highlighted {
                    Text(item.textPart)
                        .frame(height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(textPartBgColor)
                } else {
                    Text(item.textPart)
                        .frame(height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
        }.background(GeometryReader { geometry in
            if multilineEnabled {
                Color.clear.onAppear {
                    self.determineTruncation(geometry)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func renderTruncatedContent(_ lineTextParts: [TextPartsLine]) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Array(lineTextParts)) { lineTextPartsItem in
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(lineTextPartsItem.textParts) { textPartItem in
                        if textPartItem.highlighted {
                            Text(textPartItem.textPart)
                                .frame(height: 25, alignment: .leading)
                                .background(textPartBgColor)
                        } else {
                            Text(textPartItem.textPart)
                                .frame(height: 25, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func charCount(_ textParts: [TextPartOption]) -> Int {
        return textParts.reduce(0) { partialResult, textPart in
            partialResult + textPart.textPart.count
        }
    }

    private func collectLineTextParts(_ currTextParts: [TextPartOption]) -> [TextPartsLine] {
        var textParts = currTextParts
        var lineTextParts: [TextPartsLine] = []
        var currTextParts: [TextPartOption] = []
        while textParts.isNotEmpty {
            let currItem = textParts.removeFirst()
            let extraChars = charCount(currTextParts) + (currItem.textPart.count - 1) - maxLineLength
            if extraChars > 0 && (currItem.textPart.count - 1) - extraChars > 0 {
                let endIndex = currItem.textPart.index(currItem.textPart.startIndex, offsetBy: (currItem.textPart.count - 1) - extraChars)
                currTextParts.append(
                    TextPartOption(
                        index: currTextParts.count,
                        textPart: String(currItem.textPart[currItem.textPart.startIndex..<endIndex]),
                        highlighted: currItem.highlighted
                    )
                )
                lineTextParts.append(TextPartsLine(textParts: currTextParts))

                currTextParts = []
                currTextParts.append(
                    TextPartOption(
                        index: currTextParts.count,
                        textPart: String(currItem.textPart[endIndex..<currItem.textPart.index(endIndex, offsetBy: extraChars)]),
                        highlighted: currItem.highlighted
                    )
                )

            } else {
                currTextParts.append(currItem.copy(index: currTextParts.count))
            }
        }
        if currTextParts.isNotEmpty {
            lineTextParts.append(TextPartsLine(textParts: currTextParts))
        }

        return lineTextParts
    }

    private func collectTextParts(_ matches: [NSTextCheckingResult], _ textPart: String) -> [TextPartOption] {
        var textParts: [TextPartOption] = []

        // 1. Adding start non-highlighted text if exists
        if let firstMatch = matches.first, firstMatch.range.location > 0 {
            textParts.append(
                TextPartOption(
                    index: textParts.count,
                    textPart: String(text[text.startIndex..<text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: firstMatch.range.location)]),
                    highlighted: false
                )
            )
        }

        // 2. Adding highlighted text matches and non-highlighted texts in-between
        var lastMatchEndIndex: String.Index?
        for (index, match) in matches.enumerated() {
            let startIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: match.range.location)
            if (match.range.location + textPart.count) > text.count {
                lastMatchEndIndex = text.endIndex
            } else {
                lastMatchEndIndex = text.index(startIndex, offsetBy: textPart.count)
            }
            // Adding highlighted string
            textParts.append(
                TextPartOption(
                    index: textParts.count,
                    textPart: String(text[startIndex..<lastMatchEndIndex!]),
                    highlighted: true
                )
            )

            if (matches.count > index + 1 ) && (matches[index + 1].range.location != (match.range.location + textPart.count)) {
                // There is a non-highlighted string between highlighted strings
                textParts.append(
                    TextPartOption(
                        index: textParts.count,
                        textPart: String(text[lastMatchEndIndex!..<text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: matches[index + 1].range.location)]),
                        highlighted: false
                    )
                )
            }
        }

        // 3. Adding end non-highlighted text if exists
        if let lastMatch = matches.last, lastMatch.range.location < text.count {
            textParts.append(
                TextPartOption(
                    index: textParts.count,
                    textPart: String(text[lastMatchEndIndex!..<text.endIndex]),
                    highlighted: false
                )
            )
        }

        return textParts
    }

    private func collectRegexMatches(_ match: String) -> [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        let pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: match)
            .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            .folding(options: .regularExpression, locale: .current)

        // swiftlint:disable:next force_try
        return try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive).matches(
            in: text, options: .withTransparentBounds,
            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
        )
    }

    private func determineTruncation(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) {
       // Calculate the bounding box we'd need to render the
       // text given the width from the GeometryReader.
       let total = self.text.boundingRect(
           with: CGSize(
               width: geometry.size.width,
               height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude
           ),
           options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
           attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)],
           context: nil
       )

        if total.size.height > geometry.size.height {
           isTruncated = true
       } else {
           isTruncated = false
       }
   }

    private struct TextPartOption: Identifiable {
        let index: Int
        let textPart: String
        let highlighted: Bool

        var id: String { "\(index)_\(textPart)" }

        func copy(index: Int? = nil, textPart: String? = nil, highlighted: Bool? = nil) -> TextPartOption {
            return TextPartOption(
                index: index ?? self.index,
                textPart: textPart ?? self.textPart,
                highlighted: highlighted ?? self.highlighted
            )
        }
    }

    private struct TextPartsLine: Identifiable {
        let textParts: [TextPartOption]

        var id: String { textParts.reduce("") { partialResult, textPartOption in
            "\(partialResult)_\(textPartOption.id)"
        } }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
HighlightedText(
  text: item.title,
  textPart: searchQuery
)
.padding(.bottom, 2)
.foregroundColor(Color.secondaryDark)
.font(myFont)
```

Examples of the result:

[- More than one list item result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xz9b.png)

[- One Item result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loNo4.png)